# PHP 掲示板　削除機能

Tags: php, sql

現在掲示板を作ってますが、削除機能の実装ができません。
sqlの条件や、根本的なformの構成が良くないのかと思ってます。

長くなるので一部省略してます。
情報が足りなかったら、指摘お願いします。

**index.php**

```
<body>
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="head">
    <h1>掲示板</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
      <div>
      <label for="view_name">表示名</label>
      <input id="view_name" type="text" name="view_name" value="<?php if( !empty($_SESSION['view_name']) ){ echo $_SESSION['view_name']; } ?>">
      </div><br>
      <form action="index.php" method="post" id="form"><!-- javascript:void(0)-->
          <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="70" rows="15" placeholder="メモを残してください"></textarea><br>
          <input type="submit" value="書き込む" id="write">
      </form>
      <!--
      <form id="form_1" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" return false>
          <p>名前 <input type="text" name = "userid" id ="userid"> </p>
          <p>パスワード <input type="text" name = "passward" id="passward"> </p>
      </form>
      <button id="ajax">ajax</button>
      </div>
      -->
     <hr>
    <hr>
  </div>
  <?php
    $prin = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tb /*ORDER BY ban DESC*/");
    while($fet = $prin->fetch()):
      echo "ID :".nl2br($fet['id'])."<br>";
      echo nl2br($fet['mes'])."<br>";

      // 表示名の入力チェック
      if( empty($_POST['view_name']) ) {
        $error_message[] = '表示名を入力してください。';
      } else {
        $clean['view_name'] = h($_POST['view_name'], ENT_QUOTES);

        // セッションに表示名を保存
        $_SESSION['view_name'] = $clean['view_name'];
      }

  ?>
    <!--ポップアップ
    <div id="popup" style="width: 200px;display: none;padding: 30px 30px;border: 2px solid #000;margin: auto;">
      削除しますか？<br />
      <button id="ok" onclick="okfunc()">削除</button>
      <button id="no" onclick="nofunc()">キャンセル</button>
    </div>
    -->
    <divv id="functions">
      <div id="bottons" style="display:inline-flex">
        <form action="delete.php" method="post">
          <input type="submit" value="削除" id="delete">
        </form>
      </div>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require('dbconnect.php');

$id = $_POST['id'];
$del = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM tb WHERE id = $id");//ここの条件がうまくできない
$del->execute();

header('Location: index.php'); exit();
?>
```

Comment: パッと見では `index.php` 側で削除の際にボタンしか表示されていないように思います (これでは削除対象のレコードが指定されない)。 / 現在のコードを実行した場合に、どのような問題があるのかをより具体的に説明してあると、回答が付きやすいと思います。 / 質問は後からでも [編集] できるので、必要に応じて追記してみてください。

Comment: 削除ボタンを押した際に、押されたボタンの投稿のみを削除したいですが、レコードの指定の仕方が良くわかりません。

Comment: 削除したい削除投稿記事ID($_POST['id'])を指定するinputタグが無いのでサーバーに削除投稿記事IDが送信されないからでは？

Comment: formタグ内のinputタグをfor文とかで各投稿ごとにidを振っていく感じですか？

Answer (score 1):

１、**prepare、execute**　の使い方が違う。名前付きパラメータを用いて ”SQL ステートメントを準備する”指定方法と、”疑問符パラメータを用いて SQL ステートメントを準備する”指定方法がありますが、疑問符パラメータでの例です。

```
$del = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM tb WHERE id = ?");
$del->execute(array($id));
```

２、削除したい削除投稿記事ID($_POST['id'])を指定するinputタグが無いのでサーバーに削除投稿記事IDが送信されないから削除できない

詳細は以下のリンクで確認して下さい。
https://www.php.net/manual/ja/pdo.prepare.php

追記、
GETパラメータで解決した様ですが、初心を完結してもらいたいので
jqueryで　POST送信するサンプルスクリプトを追記しておきます。

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])){
    echo intval($_POST['id']); exit;
};
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    function send_post_id(pid){
        $.post( "a.php", { id: pid}).done(function( html ) { alert( html );});
    }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="send_post_id('12345')">POST 送信</a>
</body>
</html>
```

実際に試す時は、a.php として保存して下さい。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
２はformタグ内のinputタグをfor文とかで各投稿ごとにidを振っていく感じですか？

Comment: 記事IDを、delete.phpにPOSTするためには、記事毎にform（削除ボタン）を作るか、記事が何らかの方法で、選択された時に、javascriptでname="id"のinputタグへ記事IDセットするかです。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
削除ボタン部分を
<a href="delete.php?id=<?php print($fet['id']); ?>">削除</a>とし、
処理側を$id = $_REQUEST['id'];とすることで実現したいことが出来ました。

ありがとうございました！

Comment: JSバージョンの記載ありがとうございます。
調べて行くなかで、aタグの中にonclickというソースコードをたくさん見つけることが出来ました。
色々勉強になりました、ありがとうございました。